# MySQL - conditional SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql, select, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have tables `item` and `store` (it's a store management system). `item` table has a column called `store_id` and another column called `status`. `item.status` can be 'sold' or 'unsold'.

I need help writing a query which will do these things:

- select all items of all stores
- if a store has just one item and that item is 'sold', remove that item from the result set

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a filtering subquery that searches for stores with more than one item, or one unsold item.  Then you can join the subquery on the original tables, like:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  s2.store_id
        from    store s2
        join    items i2
        on      s2.store_id = i2.store_id
        group by
                s2.store_id
        having 
                count(*) > 1 -- More than one item
                or max(i2.status) = 'unsold' -- One item but unsold
        ) filter
join    store s
on      filter.store_id = s.store_id
join    items i
on      s.store_id = i.store_id
```